# Is it possible to track bash commands in real time?

Tags: bash, command-line, monitoring, command-history

I'd like to know if I can track commands entered by user in a bash shell, in real time.

What I'm trying to do is something similar to [thefuck](https://github.com/nvbn/thefuck), but I need to prompt the user as and when he enters new commands into the shell.

Is there any way I could write a hook to bash that kind of lets me wrap my code around it ?
Alternatively: is there a way to pull updated bash history? afaik bash writes to history when the shell is exited, unless you run 'history' command in the same terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `export PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'` to `/etc/profile` or other profile file. This causes the `history -a` command to execute before every command prompt display. `history -a` flushes history to `.bash_history` immediately.